# A counterexample to $Ae\simeq Ae^{\prime}\to A(1-e)\simeq A(1-e^{\prime})$

Tags: ring-theory, modules, examples-counterexamples, algebras, idempotents

Let  $e,e^{\prime}$ be two idempotents in a $k$- algebra  $A$ ($k$ is a field) . Then my guess  $Ae\simeq Ae^{\prime}$ (as a left $A$- module) does not imply $A(1-e)\simeq A(1-e^{\prime})$ in general, but I cannot find an example? can anyone please give me an example and tell me under what condition this implication is true?

According to [this](http://pages.uoregon.edu/brundan/math607winter03/ch2.pdf) lecture notes (in Lemma2.1) the above implication is true in finite dimensional algebras by using Krull-Schmidt theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right to be skeptical. As you've already noted at your other question, Artinian rings are ruled out from consideration since the Krull-Schmidt theorem can be used to prove they have the aforementioned property.

Happily, I can demonstrate a ring without the property that is even von Neumann regular. I was inspired by a theorem in Goodearl's book *von Neumann regular rings* to this effect:

> For a von Neumann regular ring $R$, $R$ is unit regular iff for all idempotents $e,e'$, $eR\cong e'R$ iff $(1-e)R\cong (1-e')R$.

With that in mind, let's go for my favorite von Neuman regular ring that isn't unit regular. Let $V$ be a countable dimensional left vector space over a field $F$, and let $R$ be its ring of linear transformations. The transformations will be written on the right of elements of $V$.

It's well known this ring $R$ is left self-injective and von Neumann reuglar and not unit regular. It has exactly one nontrivial ideal $I$: the set of transformations with finite dimensional image.

To define the following transformations, let $\{b_i\mid i\in \Bbb N\}$ be a basis for $V$.

Define three transformations:

$$e(b_i):=\begin{cases}0& \text{ if $i=0$}\\ b_i& \text{ if $i>0$}\end{cases}\\
v(b_i):=b_{2i}\\
u(b_i):=\begin{cases}0& \text{ if $i$ is odd }\\ b_{i/2}& \text{ if $i$ is even}\end{cases}
$$

It's easy to see that $e$ is idempotent and that $uv=1$. Furthermore $f=veu$ is idempotent.

We claim that $Re\cong Rf$ but $R(1-e)\ncong R(1-f)$.

Now, the map sending $re\mapsto reu$ from $Re$ to $Reu$ is injective since $u$ is right cancellable. Therefore $Re\cong Reu$. But $Reu=Rveu=Rf$.

In hopes of finding a contradiction, let's suppose that $R(1-e)$ and $R(1-f)$ are isomorphic. Since $R$ is left self-injective, the isomorphism out of $R(1-e)$ extends to an endomorphism of $R\to R$. As such, it is given by right multiplication by some element of $R$, call it $q$. So we have that $R(1-e)q=R(1-f)$.

But this is a problem: the image of $(1-e)$ is finite dimensional (one dimensional, in fact). Then $R(1-e)q$ is trapped inside the proper ideal $I$ we mentioned before. But the image of $1-f$ is infinite dimensional, so it does not lie in the ideal. Thus $R(1-e)$ and $R(1-f)$ cannot be isomorphic.

So the heart of the trick here was to find idempotents $e,f$ such that $e,f,1-f$ all had infinite dimensional images, and yet $1-e$ had a finite dimensional image. We leveraged this asymmetry to produce a counterexample.